# What happens to messages that come to a server implements stream processing after the source reached its bound?

Tags: scala, stream, akka, spark-streaming, stream-processing

Im learning akka streams but obviously its relevant to any streaming framework :)

quoting akka documentation:

> Reactive Streams is just to define a common mechanism of how to move
>   data across an asynchronous boundary without losses, buffering or
>   resource exhaustion

Now, from what I understand is that if up until before streams, lets take an http server for example, the request would come and when the receiver wasent finished with a request, so the new requests that are coming will be collected in a buffer that will hold the waiting requests, and then there is a problem that this buffer have an unknown size and at some point if the server is overloaded we can loose requests that were waiting.

So then stream processing came to play and they bounded this buffer to be controllable...so we can predefine the number of messages (requests in my example) we want to have in line and we can take care of each at a time.

my question, if we implement that a source in our server can have a 3 messages at most, so if the 4th id coming what happens with it?

I mean when another server will call us and we are already taking care of 3 requests...what will happened to he's request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is not actually the main problem that Reactive Streams implementations solve.

Backpressure in terms of the number of requests is solved with regular networking tools. For example, in Java you can configure a thread pool of a networking library (for example Netty) to some parallelism level, and the library will take care of accepting as much requests as possible. Or, if you use synchronous sockets API, it is even simpler - you can postpone calling `accept()` on the server socket until all of the currently connected clients are served. In either case, there is no "buffer" on either side, it's just until the server accepts a connection, the client will be blocked (either inside a system call for blocking APIs, or in an event loop for async APIs).

What Reactive Streams implementations solve is how to handle backpressure inside a higher-level data pipeline. Reactive streams implementations (e.g. akka-streams) provide a way to construct a pipeline of data in which, when the consumer of the data is slow, the producer will slow down automatically as well, and this would work across any kind of underlying transport, be it HTTP, WebSockets, raw TCP connections or even in-process messaging.

For example, consider a simple WebSocket connection, where the client sends a continuous stream of information (e.g. data from some sensor), and the server writes this data to some database. Now suppose that the database on the server side becomes slow for some reason (networking problems, disk overload, whatever). The server now can't keep up with the data the client sends, that is, it cannot save it to the database in time before the new piece of data arrives. If you're using a reactive streams implementation throughout this pipeline, the server will signal to the client automatically that it cannot process more data, and the client will automatically tweak its rate of producing in order not to overload the server.

Naturally, this can be done without any Reactive Streams implementation, e.g. by manually controlling acknowledgements. However, like with many other libraries, Reactive Streams implementations solve this problem for you. They also provide an easy way to define such pipelines, and usually they have interfaces for various external systems like databases. In particular, such libraries may implement backpressure on the lowest level, down to to the TCP connection, which may be hard to do manually.

As for Reactive Streams itself, it is just a description of an API which can be implemented by a library, which defines common terms and behavior and allows such libraries to be interchangeable or to interact easily, e.g. you can connect an akka-streams pipeline to a Monix pipeline using the interfaces from the specification, and the combined pipeline will work seamlessly and supporting all of the backpressure features of Reacive Streams.